# "Restarting kernel..." issue when filling list in Spyder

Tags: python, list, anaconda, spyder

Whenever I try to fill a very huge list in Spyder, even without importing any package, for example using the following code:

```
mylist=[]
for k in range(10000000000):
    mylist.append(k)
```

I get the following message:

```
Restarting kernel...
```

And the programm just stops. Has anyone any idea on why it would do that and how I can fix it ? It's very problematic since I'm using very large lists for my project.

I'm using Anaconda, Python 3.9.12 and here are my dependencies:

channels:

- pytorch
- jmcmurray
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- defaults

dependencies:

```
_libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
_openmp_mutex=4.5=2_kmp_llvm
_tflow_select=2.3.0=mkl
abseil-cpp=20211102.0=h27087fc_1
absl-py=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
aiohttp=3.8.1=py39hb9d737c_1
aiosignal=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
alabaster=0.7.12=pyhd3eb1b0_0
appdirs=1.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
arrow=1.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
astroid=2.11.7=py39h06a4308_0
astunparse=1.6.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
async-timeout=4.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
atomicwrites=1.4.0=py_0
attrs=21.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
audioread=2.1.9=py39hf3d152e_3
autopep8=1.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
babel=2.9.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
beautifulsoup4=4.11.1=py39h06a4308_0
binaryornot=0.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_1
black=19.10b0=py_0
blas=1.0=mkl
bleach=4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
blinker=1.4=py_1
bottleneck=1.3.4=py39hce1f21e_0
brotli=1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
brotli-bin=1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
brotlipy=0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003
bzip2=1.0.8=h7f98852_4
c-ares=1.18.1=h7f98852_0
ca-certificates=2022.6.15=ha878542_0
cached-property=1.5.2=hd8ed1ab_1
cached_property=1.5.2=pyha770c72_1
cachetools=5.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
certifi=2022.6.15=py39hf3d152e_0
cffi=1.15.1=py39h74dc2b5_0
chardet=4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003
charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
click=8.0.4=py39h06a4308_0
cloudpickle=2.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama=0.4.5=py39h06a4308_0
cookiecutter=1.7.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography=37.0.1=py39h9ce1e76_0
cudatoolkit=11.3.1=h2bc3f7f_2
cycler=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
dbus=1.13.18=hb2f20db_0
debugpy=1.5.1=py39h295c915_0
decorator=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch=20200713=pyhd3eb1b0_0
dill=0.3.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
docutils=0.18.1=py39h06a4308_3
entrypoints=0.4=py39h06a4308_0
et_xmlfile=1.1.0=py39h06a4308_0
expat=2.4.4=h295c915_0
ffmpeg=4.3.2=hca11adc_0
flake8=4.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1
flatbuffers=2.0.6=h27087fc_0
fontconfig=2.13.1=h6c09931_0
fonttools=4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype=2.11.0=h70c0345_0
frozenlist=1.3.1=py39hb9d737c_0
gast=0.5.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
gettext=0.19.8.1=h0b5b191_1005
giflib=5.2.1=h7b6447c_0
glib=2.69.1=h4ff587b_1
gmp=6.2.1=h58526e2_0
gnutls=3.6.13=h85f3911_1
google-auth=2.10.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
google-pasta=0.2.0=pyh8c360ce_0
grpc-cpp=1.46.3=hbd84cd8_2
grpcio=1.46.3=py39h7ad10b3_2
gst-plugins-base=1.14.0=h8213a91_2
gstreamer=1.14.0=h28cd5cc_2
h5py=3.1.0=nompi_py39h25020de_100
hdf5=1.10.6=nompi_h7c3c948_1111
icu=58.2=he6710b0_3
idna=3.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagesize=1.4.1=py39h06a4308_0
imbalanced-learn=0.9.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
importlib-metadata=4.11.3=py39h06a4308_0
importlib_metadata=4.11.3=hd3eb1b0_0
inflection=0.5.1=py39h06a4308_0
intel-openmp=2021.4.0=h06a4308_3561
intervaltree=3.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel=6.9.1=py39h06a4308_0
ipython=7.31.1=py39h06a4308_1
ipython_genutils=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort=5.9.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi=0.18.1=py39h06a4308_1
jeepney=0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
jellyfish=0.9.0=py39h7f8727e_0
jinja2=3.0.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2-time=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
joblib=1.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg=9e=h7f8727e_0
jsonschema=4.4.0=py39h06a4308_0
jupyter_client=7.2.2=py39h06a4308_0
jupyter_core=4.10.0=py39h06a4308_0
jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=py_0
keras=2.8.0=py39h06a4308_0
keras-preprocessing=1.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
keyring=23.4.0=py39h06a4308_0
kiwisolver=1.4.2=py39h295c915_0
krb5=1.19.2=hac12032_0
lame=3.100=h7f98852_1001
lazy-object-proxy=1.6.0=py39h27cfd23_0
lcms2=2.12=h3be6417_0
ld_impl_linux-64=2.38=h1181459_1
libblas=3.9.0=12_linux64_mkl
libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
libcblas=3.9.0=12_linux64_mkl
libclang=10.0.1=default_hb85057a_2
libcurl=7.84.0=h91b91d3_0
libedit=3.1.20210910=h7f8727e_0
libev=4.33=h516909a_1
libevent=2.1.12=h8f2d780_0
libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
libflac=1.3.4=h27087fc_0
libgcc-ng=12.1.0=h8d9b700_16
libgfortran-ng=7.5.0=h14aa051_20
libgfortran4=7.5.0=h14aa051_20
liblapack=3.9.0=12_linux64_mkl
libllvm10=10.0.1=hbcb73fb_5
libllvm11=11.1.0=hf817b99_2
libnghttp2=1.47.0=h727a467_0
libogg=1.3.4=h7f98852_1
libopus=1.3.1=h7f98852_1
libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
libpq=12.9=h16c4e8d_3
libprotobuf=3.20.1=h6239696_0
librosa=0.9.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
libsndfile=1.0.31=h9c3ff4c_1
libsodium=1.0.18=h7b6447c_0
libspatialindex=1.9.3=h2531618_0
libssh2=1.10.0=ha56f1ee_2
libstdcxx-ng=12.1.0=ha89aaad_16
libtiff=4.2.0=h2818925_1
libuuid=1.0.3=h7f8727e_2
libvorbis=1.3.7=h9c3ff4c_0
libwebp=1.2.2=h55f646e_0
libwebp-base=1.2.2=h7f8727e_0
libxcb=1.15=h7f8727e_0
libxkbcommon=1.0.1=hfa300c1_0
libxml2=2.9.14=h74e7548_0
libxslt=1.1.35=h4e12654_0
libzlib=1.2.12=h166bdaf_2
llvm-openmp=14.0.4=he0ac6c6_0
llvmlite=0.38.1=py39h7d9a04d_0
lz4-c=1.9.3=h295c915_1
markdown=3.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
markupsafe=2.1.1=py39h7f8727e_0
matplotlib=3.5.1=py39h06a4308_1
matplotlib-base=3.5.1=py39ha18d171_1
matplotlib-inline=0.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_2
mccabe=0.6.1=py39h06a4308_2
mistune=0.8.4=py39h27cfd23_1000
mkl=2021.4.0=h06a4308_640
mkl-service=2.4.0=py39h7f8727e_0
mkl_fft=1.3.1=py39hd3c417c_0
mkl_random=1.2.2=py39h51133e4_0
multidict=6.0.2=py39hb9d737c_1
munkres=1.1.4=py_0
mypy_extensions=0.4.3=py39h06a4308_1
nbclient=0.5.13=py39h06a4308_0
nbconvert=6.4.4=py39h06a4308_0
nbformat=5.3.0=py39h06a4308_0
ncurses=6.3=h5eee18b_3
nest-asyncio=1.5.5=py39h06a4308_0
nettle=3.6=he412f7d_0
nspr=4.33=h295c915_0
nss=3.74=h0370c37_0
numba=0.55.2=py39h66db6d7_0
numexpr=2.8.1=py39h807cd23_2
numpy=1.22.4=py39hc58783e_0
numpydoc=1.4.0=py39h06a4308_0
oauthlib=3.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
openh264=2.1.1=h4ff587b_0
openpyxl=3.0.9=pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl=1.1.1q=h166bdaf_0
opt_einsum=3.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
os=0.1.4=0
packaging=21.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas=1.4.2=py39h295c915_0
pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pathlib=1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1
pathspec=0.9.0=py39h06a4308_0
pcre=8.45=h295c915_0
pexpect=4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow=9.2.0=py39hace64e9_1
pip=22.1.2=py39h06a4308_0
platformdirs=2.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pluggy=1.0.0=py39h06a4308_1
ply=3.11=py39h06a4308_0
pooch=1.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
poyo=0.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit=3.0.20=pyhd3eb1b0_0
protobuf=3.20.1=py39h5a03fae_0
psutil=5.9.0=py39h5eee18b_0
ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
pyasn1-modules=0.2.7=py_0
pycodestyle=2.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydocstyle=6.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydub=0.25.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pyflakes=2.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments=2.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt=2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pylint=2.14.5=py39h06a4308_0
pyls-spyder=0.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyparsing=3.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt=5.15.7=py39h6a678d5_1
pyqt5-sip=12.11.0=py39h6a678d5_1
pyrsistent=0.18.0=py39heee7806_0
pysocks=1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0
pysoundfile=0.10.3.post1=pyhd3deb0d_0
python=3.9.12=h12debd9_1
python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema=2.15.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-flatbuffers=2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
python-lsp-black=1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-jsonrpc=1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-server=1.3.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-slugify=5.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi=3.9=2_cp39
pytorch=1.12.1=py3.9_cuda11.3_cudnn8.3.2_0
pytorch-mutex=1.0=cuda
pytz=2022.1=py39h06a4308_0
pyu2f=0.1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pyxdg=0.27=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyyaml=6.0=py39h7f8727e_1
pyzmq=23.2.0=py39h6a678d5_0
qdarkstyle=3.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer=0.1.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt-main=5.15.2=h327a75a_7
qt-webengine=5.15.9=hd2b0992_4
qtawesome=1.0.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole=5.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy=2.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtwebkit=5.212=h4eab89a_4
qutil=3.2.1=6
re2=2022.06.01=h27087fc_0
readline=8.1.2=h7f8727e_1
regex=2022.7.9=py39h5eee18b_0
requests=2.28.1=py39h06a4308_0
requests-oauthlib=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
resampy=0.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
rope=0.22.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
rsa=4.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
rtree=0.9.7=py39h06a4308_1
scikit-learn=1.1.1=py39h6a678d5_0
scipy=1.7.3=py39hc147768_0
seaborn=0.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
secretstorage=3.3.1=py39h06a4308_0
setuptools=61.2.0=py39h06a4308_0
sip=6.6.2=py39h6a678d5_0
six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
snappy=1.1.9=hbd366e4_1
snowballstemmer=2.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers=2.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
soupsieve=2.3.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx=5.0.2=py39h06a4308_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp=1.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp=1.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp=2.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath=1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp=1.0.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml=1.1.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder=5.2.2=py39h06a4308_1
spyder-kernels=2.2.1=py39h06a4308_0
sqlite=3.39.2=h5082296_0
tbb=2021.5.0=h924138e_1
tensorboard=2.8.0=py39h06a4308_0
tensorboard-data-server=0.6.0=py39hd97740a_2
tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
tensorflow=2.8.2=mkl_py39ha986a27_0
tensorflow-base=2.8.2=mkl_py39hf890080_0
tensorflow-estimator=2.8.0=py39hb070fc8_0
termcolor=1.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_3
testpath=0.6.0=py39h06a4308_0
text-unidecode=1.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance=4.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
threadpoolctl=3.1.0=pyh8a188c0_0
three-merge=0.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
time=1.8=h516909a_0
tinycss=0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_1002
tk=8.6.12=h1ccaba5_0
toml=0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli=2.0.1=py39h06a4308_0
tomlkit=0.11.1=py39h06a4308_0
torchvision=0.13.1=py39_cu113
tornado=6.1=py39h27cfd23_0
tqdm=4.64.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
traitlets=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
typed-ast=1.4.3=py39h7f8727e_1
typing-extensions=4.3.0=py39h06a4308_0
typing_extensions=4.3.0=py39h06a4308_0
tzdata=2022a=hda174b7_0
ujson=5.4.0=py39h6a678d5_0
unidecode=1.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3=1.26.11=py39h06a4308_0
watchdog=2.1.6=py39h06a4308_0
wcwidth=0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings=0.5.1=py39h06a4308_1
werkzeug=2.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
wheel=0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
wrapt=1.14.1=py39h5eee18b_0
wurlitzer=3.0.2=py39h06a4308_0
x264=1!161.3030=h7f98852_1
xz=5.2.5=h7f8727e_1
yaml=0.2.5=h7b6447c_0
yapf=0.31.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
yarl=1.7.2=py39hb9d737c_2
zeromq=4.3.4=h2531618_0
zipp=3.8.0=py39h06a4308_0
zlib=1.2.12=h7f8727e_2
zstd=1.5.2=ha4553b6_0
```

Comment: You can't store 10 billion ints in a list, with 4 bytes per int, that  would make 40GB size, you should find another way for your program instead, that isn't a good way

Comment: My example was probably a bit too hardcore, but I'm trying to understand why the "Restarting kernel..." pops up. Sometimes, it is at my 600th file, but sometimes it is at my 1000th file for the same programm and I don't understand what it means and how i can fix it. Each file adds aproximately 800 elements to the list, so for the 1008 files that I have, I need to store at least 806400 elements in a list. How can I do that ? What's the better way ?

Comment: What azro writes seems to be your problem, you could try to save intermedia parts of your list to avoid holding them all in memory at once. But 806.400 int elements should not be a problem unless the elements are not integers in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! It's not only integers but also float and str types. I'll try to save my list to a new file every 100 file and see if it works better. What's strange is that it worked in another environment and not in this one, but anyway, the way I did things seem to be inefficient so I'll change it.